# fitnesse slim java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, eclipse, classcastexception, fitnesse-slim

I am working with fitnesse. And although i have worked on Fitnesse maintenance before, this is the first time i am implementing it.

Everything seems to be in place but I get the below exception on my wiki page when I execute the test.

Fitnesse Wiki Page

[image: Fitnesse Wiki Page]

On investigation I see that the program exits from the following step:

The execution exits from this debug statement
[image: The execution exits from this debug statement]

The data is correctly retrieved as required. I am using the Query table here for comparing my data. All the values are inserted into nested Lists till I reached the singular values i need in each cell on fitnesse wiki apage. The message variable in this method has the following exception:

```
000002:000014:queryTable_2_1:001810:__EXCEPTION__:fitnesse.slim.SlimError: message:<<NO_METHOD_IN_CLASS table[1] com.ezops.fitnesse.smoketest.SmokeTestConfigReader.>>
    at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutionResult$NoMethod.returnValue(MethodExecutionResult.java:28) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.call(StatementExecutor.java:103) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.CallInstruction.executeInternal(CallInstruction.java:35) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.Instruction.execute(Instruction.java:29) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatement(ListExecutor.java:49) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatements(ListExecutor.java:43) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor.execute(ListExecutor.java:85) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.executeInstructions(SlimServer.java:82) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processOneSetOfInstructions(SlimServer.java:75) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.tryProcessInstructions(SlimServer.java:62) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.serve(SlimServer.java:47) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.handle(SlimService.java:168) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.acceptOne(SlimService.java:176) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.accept(SlimService.java:138) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.startWithFactory(SlimService.java:91) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.main(SlimService.java:56) [fitnesse-standalone.jar:20161106]:]
```

Answer (score 0):

On further analysis I realized that the issue was due to exceeded length of the result.

The length of the parameter being passed to be written to OutputStream.write() method should not exceed the length of BufferedOutputStream.buf variable. If it does then the program exits showing the ClassCastException on Fitnesse Wiki Page.